# Ruby's Case statement vs Javascript's Switch statement

Tags: javascript, ruby, switch-statement, conditional-statements, case

I just learned Javascript's Switch statement and thought it works the same way as Ruby's Case statement. However it is slightly different and I don't understand why the Switch statement will keep printing out the rest of the lines. Please see comparison example below:

```
    option = 2
    case option
    when 1 
      print "You selected option 1."
    when 2
      print "You selected option 2."
    when 3
      print "You selected option 3."
    when 4
      print "You selected option 4."
    end
```

Above case statement in Ruby will only print out: `You selected option 2.`

However, when it translated into a Javascript's Switch statement:

```
    var option = 2
    switch (option) {
      case 1:
        console.log("You selected option 1.");
      case 2:
        console.log("You selected option 2.");
      case 3:
        console.log("You selected option 3.");
      case 4:
        console.log("You selected option 4.");
    }
```

The above Switch statement will prints

```
    You selected option 2.
    You selected option 3.
    You selected option 4.
```

I will have to put a `break` after each case in the Switch statement to make it work.

Can someone please explain why and is there a simpler way or method to do it in Javascript?

Comment: You will have to add a `break` after each case. This is how the language is designed. Along with Java, C, PHP, and pretty much every language under the sun.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: "pretty much every language under the sun." While the rest of the comment is perfectly on-point, this is patently false. It is just the family of languages whose syntax is heavily inspired by C. For example, Lisp, Elixir, Pascal, Modula 2, Perl, Fortran and many others take the same approach Ruby does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript follows the C tradition in requiring an explicit `break` to break out of a `switch`. C++ and Java are the same in that respect, as well as (I'm sure) countless other C derivatives.

To get out of a `case`:

```
switch (something) {
  case value:
    console.log("whatever");
    break;
  case other:
    console.log("other");
    break;
}
```

Without the `break`, execution "falls through" to subsequent `case` blocks.